# How do I check whether remote directory exist or not on SFtp using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh2-sftp

I need to check whether a remote directory exists or not on sFtp connection.

I am using the condition like,

```
if (!sftp.Exists(remotePath))
```

I am using the library [ssh2-sftp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client) but it doesn't allow me to use the Exist methods because it doesn't have that function.

Can anybody suggest me what should I do for checking for remote directory exist or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use `list`

```
sftp.list(remotePath);
```

It will (asynchronously) trigger an error if the file doesn't exist

Comment: I want to check if the directory exists or not directory may or may not be having a file inside.